# Не могу получить коллекцию ячеек через DOM используя другой вариант

Tags: javascript, dom, table

Идея такая, хочу получить доступ к любой ячейке и задавать свойства или значения.
Первый вариант работает, но с ним работать, нет смысла.

При запуске второго варианта возникает ошибка, что таблица пустая, и код дальше не работает. Почему? Область видимости или что то другое? Я искал в гугл, но так и не смог найти ответа.

Я пробую через замыкания это сделать, я только начал их учить, практиковать.
Код я буду улучшать. Пока мне надо понять  в чем проблема.
Как должен работать мой код.

1. Вызываем функцию, задаем ряд (rows1) где будем брать ячейку.
2. Получаем таблицу. (Ведь таблица не пустая, но почему ошибка)?

   ```
   var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');
   ```
3. Получаем коллекции.
4. Потом через метод получу элемент массива.

Правильно ли я его написал чтоб эти шаги были выполнены?
Если есть ошибки, напишите что не так.
Спасибо.

```
<table id="tableCinema" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>    
            <td >3</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
        </tr>           
    </table>    
    <button onclick="addObj()">add</button>
```

//*****************************************************

```
var arrMovies = [
     {name: "Simpsons", time: "14:20"},
     {name: "Zootopia", time: "18:30"},
     {name: "Avatar", time: "19:00"},
     {name: "Boss", time: "11:40"}
];

function addObj() {
  var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');
  var trsTable = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var tdsTable = trsTable[2].getElementsByTagName('td');

  function addValue(arrElem) {
    tdsTable[1].innerHtml = arrMovies[arrElem].name;
    tdsTable[2].innerHtml = arrMovies[arrElem].time;
  }
  tdsTable[1].innerHTML = arrMovies[3].name;
}

//Это второй вариант. 
function addObj2(rows1){
    var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');

  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
  //TypeError: table is null
    var trsTable = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
    var tdsTable = trsTable[rows1].getElementsByTagName('td');
    function addValue (arrElem) {
        tdsTable[1].innerHtml = arrMovies[arrElem].name;
        tdsTable[2].innerHtml = arrMovies[arrElem].time;
    }
    console.log(tdsTable[1].innerHTML);
}

var rows2 = addObj2(2);
rows2(1);
```

Comment: а зачем при вызове функции идет создание переменной, ведь ничего не возвращается var rows2 = addObj2(2); и второе, при вызове этой функции должно работать, а вот при нажатии на кнопку не передается аргумент в функцию addObj2

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, у вас идет дублирование кода addValue, это уже нехорошо.

Во-вторых, когда в форме мы вызываете addObj2 вы даете пустой параметр, поэтому он кричит это

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

Он не может прочитать пустой параметр, вместо rows1 он кладет Null

```
var tdsTable = trsTable[rows1].getElementsByTagName('td');
```

В-третьих, вы определяете метод addValue, но нигде не используете ни в addObj, ни в addObj2, поэтому инфа нигде не добавляется.

В-четвертых, это уже совет. Используйте TextContent вместо InnerHtml

Comment: Спасибо за совет про TextContent, мощная вещь.

Comment: @МишаПодлевских Да не за что.